# (Cont'd) ROS build customization inconsistency

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just curious that in $(ROS_ROOT)/rosconfig.cmake (in my case /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/rosconfig.cmake) in diamonback on my environment, still seems to remain contradictory as discussed [here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/ROS-build-customization-inconsistency-td2774006.html) although I found it was fixed ([here](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110404.150402.6af5afb8.en.html)). Does this mean the spec is changed afterward or else?

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to point out the stuff like this though)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11054/(cont%27d)-ros-build-customization-inconsistency/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [fix](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/13604) was committed in April, after the Diamondback release.  As it was just a change to comments, I didn't backport the fix to Diamondback.  Electric will have the comments that correctly describe the configuration behavior.

Note that the behavior hasn't changed; we're just talking about the documentation of the behavior.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1